# Class for catching error and logging

Tags: java, android, error-handling, logging

I often write something like this in my code:

```
try {
    obj.doSomething();
} catch (Throwable exception) {
    // there is no need to interrupt application
    String exceptionMessage = String.valueOf(exception.getMessage());
    Log.e("Name of my app", exceptionMessage, exception);
    // and may be something else
}
```

So I wrote this simple class:

```
public class TryHelper {

    public static final TryHelper LOGGER = new TryHelper(new Handler<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Throwable exception) {
            LogUtils.exception(exception);
        }
    });

    private final Handler<Throwable> exceptionHandler;

    public TryHelper(Handler<Throwable> exceptionHandler) {
        this.exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
    }

    public void tryDoIt(Runnable runnable) {
        try {
            runnable.run();
        } catch (Throwable exception) {
            exceptionHandler.handle(exception);
        }
    }

    public void tryDoIt(RunnableAbleToThrowCheckedException runnable) {
        try {
            runnable.run();
        } catch (Throwable exception) {
            exceptionHandler.handle(exception);
        }
    }

}
```

And interfaces from my own `util` package:

```
public interface RunnableAbleToThrowCheckedException {
    void run() throws Exception;
}

public interface Handler<T> {
    void handle(T obj);
}
```

Using:

```
TryHelper.LOGGER.tryDoIt(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        obj.doSomething();
    }
});
```

1. But I'm pretty bad at English. So I need your help in choosing proper names (instead of `TryHelper`, `RunnableAbleToThrowCheckedException`, `tryDoIt()`, etc.).

   I'm a fan of Uncle Bob and his book *"Clean Code"*:

   > We want the code to read like a top-down narrative.
2. And what do you think about the need for this class? Maybe it was a bad idea?

Comment: Yes, most definitely not needed. You're creating a lot of overhead that saves you.. 0 lines of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 2) And what do you think about the need for this class? Maybe it was a bad idea?

As Jeroen said in a comment:

> Yes, most definitely not needed. You're creating a lot of overhead that saves you.. 0 lines of code.

But first things first:

```
String exceptionMessage = String.valueOf(exception.getMessage());
Log.e("Name of my app", exceptionMessage, exception);
```

I understand that you're doing this because the possibility of `getMessage` returning null, but a slightly better way in my opinion would be:

```
Log.e("Name of my app", "An error occurred while doing xxx for yyy: " + exception.getMessage(), exception);
```

---

```
} catch (Throwable exception) {
```

Catching all `Throwable`s is a very bad idea<sup>TM</sup>, as there are plenty of throwables that are not meant to be caught. This includes [OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) and [StackOverflowError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) which are among the worst, but then also some `RuntimeExcerption`s which indicate a logic error in your code, including:

- [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)
- [IllegalStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html)
- [IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html)
- [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

These exceptions should never be caught, *code should be written in a way so that they don't occur in the first place!*

---

```
public static final TryHelper LOGGER
```

There is no reason to wrap this in a singleton instance, you could just make the `tryDoIt`-methods static.

---

Overall, as you've already extracted a logging method for logging exceptions to `LogUtils.exception(exception);`, whenever you feel tempted to call this `tryDoIt` method (wherever you would put it), instead do this:

```
try {
    // do stuff that you actually want to do (i.e. do *not* call a runnable)
}
catch (SpecificException exception) {
    LogUtils.exception(exception);
}
```

This will make it a lot clearer to see which actual exceptions that can be thrown by which code. Avoid catching the overly-generic `Throwable` and `Exception`. *Only catch the exceptions that need to be caught.*

Answer (score 7):

1. You could use [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of `RunnableAbleToThrowCheckedException`. Its call method could `throw Exeption`s and has a return value too. You can use  `Void` as a type parameter and return `null` if you don't need these features:

   ```
   public class MyCallable implements Callable<Void> {

       @Override
       public Void call() throws Exception {
           ...
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
2. `TryHelper` seems like an [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) to me. I'd name it `ErrorHandlerExecutor` and rename its `tryDoIt` methods to `submit` (similar to [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)). I guess most developers would find it familiar.
3. `errorLoggerExecutor` seems a fair name for an instance which logs the errors of the submitted tasks.
4. I would also rename `Handler` to `ErrorHandler` to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeroen says in the comments:

> Yes, most definitely not needed. You're creating a lot of overhead
>   that saves you.. 0 lines of code

That said, given that you're logging exception messages, why not roll that exception code (both lines) in to a method of `Log` that simply takes an `Exception` class?

Comment: I believe that part is precisely what is done in `LogUtils.exception(exception);` ? I don't see how your answer differs from my answer here.